# Swift View Controller won't dismiss

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview

so I have a basic game going in Xcode. I started with Xcode's basic game template and built my game mostly inside the 'GameScene.swift'. When I finished with my game I wanted to add a start screen with a play button so I made a new UIViewController and added a button. I control click and dragged the button to the GameViewController and created a Modal Segue. I then wanted the game to go back when the player died. I tried various ways to dismiss the view but none worked. I am new to swift and really need help. Let me know what code/info is needed to find a solution. I have tried everything I have found on the internet. I thought I found a way around it by adding a button and Segue to the GameViewController to the menu but after multiple pushed it clogged the system and slowed to a crawl because none were dismissed. I can provide any code needed.

Inside of GameViewController.swift in the GameViewController class I tried making a function that was called when the game ended. 
I tried to both pop and dismiss the view controller. The function was called and a line printed to console but the view remained. The only thing printed to console is 'nil'

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
   func end(){
     print(navigationController?.viewControllers as Any)
     self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
     self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

[@ Vollan heres the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEcZJ.png)

[Here is the screenshot of the storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdIuT.png).

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your code you have tried various ways to dismiss the view

Comment: added it to the question! Im not sure other info to provide so just let me know. I know the question isn't very clear I'm sorry but I'm very new to swift.

Answer (score 14):

If you pushed the viewController you use `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`

If you presented it modally you use
`self.dismiss(self, animated: true)`

When its presented from a modal segue you use
`self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: This Is what I found when I looked up the problem. When I tried implementing it, it didn't do anything even thought function was called.

Comment: Try printing the viewController stack: `print(navigationController?.viewControllers)` and see what viewcontrollers you have opened. it sounds wierd that pop or dismiss wouldn't work. The only scenario where that happens is when there are no other viewcontrollers in the stack. Do you maybe dismiss the previous viewcontroller when pushing?

Comment: im not currently able to test that but I will try later today, thank you! as for dismissing when pushing im not sure. all I did was control-click and drag the button to the GameViewController and tried Modal Segue.

Comment: I tried to print the stack.  and the only thing printed to console was error, the default value I chose.

    func end(){
       print(navigationController?.viewControllers ?? "error")
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

Comment: @NathanAnderson try `self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` instead then

Comment: in the printed line?

Comment: Instead of `dismiss()`

Comment: Still nothing. I have no idea why. I added a picture of the storyboard to the question. let me know what other files you need. Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: Are there better ways of switching scenes? I just want it to watch scenes with the animation slide up from bottom.

Comment: I always to everything programmatically, i really don't like storyboards at all. What you can do is create an IB action to your button and do `let vc = gameViewController()` and then `self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)` then you get it modally presented and `dismiss` should work for sure.

Comment: Thank You! I won't be able to test for a little while but I will let you know what happens when I do.

Comment: I am now getting a new error. I attached a screenshot to the question of what it says.

Comment: In that line you are saying "This view HAS TO BE a SKView (maybe)" Remove the "?" at SKView

Comment: Right, and in a UIViewController, the View is never a SKView, so that wont pass i think

Comment: that line was put their by default when I chose the 'game' template. If I remove the menu view controller and set the GameViewController to appear first it doesn't give me any error.

Comment: Removing the question mark doesn't work. It gives me an error in the compiler. I think I  will try using a navigation controller instead of pushing it. I just wanted to use push for the pop up animation.

Answer (score 0):

I have a modal segue in a storyboard from one view controller to the other. Then I have a button that's connected to an IBAction that just runs 
`dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Check and redo the connections from the storyboard to the code. Xcode sometimes just looses a connection when making a lot of changes to the code.

Comment: mine is not connected by an IBAction